# DataGridView e.ColumnIndex out of range

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a `datagridview` that no matter what cell I click on returns an out of index error.

When I debug the following code I get a `-1` value for `e.ColumnIndex`. As for `e.RowIndex`, I get the correct row that I have clicked on.

```
 private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        form2.value = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString();
    }
```

I have tried to replace the `e.ColumnIndex` with a static int just to see if it works. When I add the int it doesn't do anything when I click on a particular row or column.

Anyone any ideas how I can change the `ColumnIndex` or how I can work around this issue.

Comment: Have you bound data to the grid view?

Comment: yea i have data in grid view. No problems with that just when i select a row it returns a -1 value for e.ColumnIndex

Comment: `if (e.RowIndex > 0 && e.ColumnIndex > 0) { ... }` Write Inside this..

Comment: Can you access the source data for the value?

Comment: I have now added the validation statement thanks but just need to fix the value that im selecting.

Comment: this code works fine for a datagridview whose datasource is an datatable

Comment: My source for the datagridview is a datatable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

-1 for `e.ColumnIndex` indicates that the `RowHeader` is being selected. Are you sure you don't have the `RowSelected` event bound to this event as well?

In any case, it is good practice to have checks of `e.ColumnIndex` and `e.RowIndex` that both are 0 or greater in any `CellClick` event- the `RowHeader` and `ColumnHeader` cells will also fire this event when clicked, and would not contain data, which would be somewhat confusing for users.

Comment: I just have the cell clicked event bound to this event

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
        private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.RowIndex == -1) return;
            if (e.ColumnIndex == -1) return;
            Console.WriteLine(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString());
        }
```